# A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1 ]?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, sql-server-ce

I've written some basic code to parse a CSV file and input the data into a database at runtime. Variations of this code (for different delimiters and columns) have been working fine for numerous csv files, however for some reason now this code is giving me an error for a 2-column file.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Rawdata\Salesman.csv"))
{
    string line;
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        StringBuilder segment = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0, segno = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i] != '\t')
            {
                segment.Append(line[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                switch (segno)
                {
                    case 0:
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", segment.ToString());

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", segment.ToString());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                segno++;
                segment.Clear();
            }
        }

        delCmd = "INSERT INTO sales_codes (code, name) VALUES (@code, @name)";
        cmd.CommandText = delCmd;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        query.Clear();
    }
}
```

The exception being thrown is:

```
SqlCeException - A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1 ]
```

I've double and triple checked everything from the file, the code to the table schema and all looks well. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible you need to set the command text prior to the parameters?

Comment: Also, you're setting the parameters in a `swith/case` statement. Are  you sure that they are set for *every line* of your CSV?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but tried putting the command text before adding the parameters with no joy - plus it's been working fine for other files I've been parsing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is now, your code will only add parameters when a tab (`\t`) is found. If each line doesn't end with a tab, the second parameter will not be added. This could be your problem.

Comment: A bit confused as I noticed that and amended it, but was still receiving the error. However, when I explicity set the paramters like cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", "Test"); etc, it works so there must be an error somewhere in the parsing section, I'm sure I'll get to the bottom of it though. Thanks.